# Bash Find Files/Folders that Don't Belong to Permissions - Execute Multiple Commands

Tags: bash, find

I have the command close, but it doesn't seem to be executing the commands.

```
find /folder \! -user USERNAME -o -not -group GROUPNAME -o -not -perm 750 -exec chown USERNAME:GROUPNAME {} \; -exec chmod 750 {} \;
```

Comment: The exec looks OK. Does the find returns files?

Comment: @Eran since `-exec` is present in the expression, `find` will not print filenames.

Comment: The command finds the files ok and outputs them -- If i remove the -exec commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find`'s manual says (highlight's mine):

> `expression -o expression`
>
> Alternation of primaries; the OR operator. **The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is true.**

For your invocation that means, if the file currently being processed doesn't belong to user `USERNAME` or group `GROUPNAME`, `find` will leave it as it is and skip to next one, and if its permission bits doesn't match `750`, then `chown` and `chmod` will be run.

To make it work, you need to place parens around expressions to force their precedence, like:

```
find /folder ! \( -user USERNAME -group GROUPNAME -perm 750 \) \
     -exec echo chown USERNAME:GROUPNAME {} \; \
     -exec echo chmod 750 {} \;
```

If its output looks good, remove `echo`s.

And also note that both `chown` and `chmod` can operate on multiple files at once, so you can replace `\;`s with `+`s and save time.

Comment: I can't seem to get any outputs with this

Comment: Ok, thx! your code does what I was looking for after you changed it! :-)

Comment: should you change your reply to : find /folder \( ! -user USERNAME -o ! -group GROUPNAME -o ! -perm 750 \)

Comment: `! \( -user USERNAME -group GROUPNAME -perm 750 \)` is a shorthand for `\( ! -user USERNAME -o ! -group GROUPNAME -o ! -perm 750 \)`.